# tipo de variable html

Tags: javascript, html, string, conversión-de-tipos, numero

Si tengo:

```html
<b><"div">43<"/div"></b>
```

y cojo ese 43 con `textContent` o `innerHTML` y lo guardo en una variable "numero", para compararlo con otro número sería:

```js
if(numero == 5) {...}
```

o

```js
if(numero == '5') {...}
```

Yo lo hago de la primera forma y me sirve, aunque en un video lo hacen de la segunda forma y sirve.

En resumen ¿La variable número se extrae como string o como number?

Comment: ¿Has leído la documentación de [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) o de [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)? La primera devuelve un [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/conflicting/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) que es un `string` o cadena de texto, y el segundo también devuelve un `string`. Entonces comparar cadenas con valores numéricos usando `==` hace que el motor de JS realice el *cast* adecuado. Lo usual en JS es usar comparación estricta con `===`.

Comment: No sé que videos estás viendo, pero te sugiero que repases operadores de comparación y que siempre te dirijas a la documentación. Allí siempre encontrarás el valor devuelto o la firma de los métodos y funciones.

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta a tu pregunta ***¿La variable número se extrae como `string` o como `number`?*** es: son valores de tipo cadena (`string`).

**Valores devueltos**

Según la documentación de [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) y de [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), ambas propiedades devuelven un valor de cadena, aunque `textContent` puede devolver `null` si no existe contenido en el elemento.

En el caso de `innerHTML`, se devuelve un [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/conflicting/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), que es una cadena codificada en UTF-16.

**Comparación**

Realizar la [comparación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) de una cadena de texto con un valor numérico en JS usando el operador de [comparación simple o débil](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality):

```js
if ("5" == 5) { ... }
```

producirá el *cast* o conversión de uno de los operandos al tipo del otro (si es posible) y luego realizará la comparación del contenido, es decir, el valor numérico `5` será *casteado* a la cadena "5", y luego se compararán ambas cadenas.

```js
console.log("5" == 5); // true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Por otro lado, si usas [comparación estricta](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) (`===`), el resultado anterior devolverá `false`:

```js
console.log("5" === 5); // false
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Esto es porque el operador de comparación estricta, no realiza el *cast* de los operandos y compara no sólo sus valores sino sus tipos. Por lo cual, si una variable es de tipo numérica y la otra de tipo cadena, la comparación estricta devolverá `false` ya que son tipos diferentes.

La recomendación es siempre usar comparación estricta, ya que es más confiable y segura, además cuando una aplicación en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) se hace grande y compleja, muchos errores por usar comparación débil pueden llegar a pasar desapercibidos y cuesta bastante depurarlos.

Answer (score 0):

**¿La variable número se extrae como string o como number?**

Se extrae como `String`

---

Y sobre:

```
if(numero == 5) {...}
// o
if(numero == '5') {...}
```

Tu estas realizando una [comparación débil](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) en ambos casos, en el primer `if` javascript convierte la variable `numero` a un valor numérico y compara; en cambio en el segundo caso al ser ambos operando del mismo tipo (String) solo compara que tengan la misma cadena.

Yo te recomiendo usar la primera forma

**¿Por qué?**

Digamos que tienes esto:

```js
console.log("Comparación String/Number");
console.log("textContent", numero.textContent == 5);
console.log("innerHTML", numero.innerHTML  == 5);

console.log("================================");

console.log("Comparación String/String");
console.log("textContent", numero.textContent == '5');
console.log("innerHTML", numero.innerHTML  == '5');
```

```html
<div id="numero">5</div>
```

Da el resultado esperado, pero ahora modifico el `div` y añado saltos de lineas y espacios, que es habitual cuando se formatea el código HTML

```js
console.log("Comparación String/Number");
console.log("textContent", numero.textContent == 5);
console.log("innerHTML", numero.innerHTML  == 5);

console.log("================================");

console.log("Comparación String/String");
console.log("textContent", numero.textContent == '5');
console.log("innerHTML", numero.innerHTML  == '5');
```

```html
<div id="numero">
 5 
</div>
```

Como se puede observar en el ejemplo anterior, solo de la primera forma retorna el resultado esperado (ya que hubo una conversión), razón por la cual en este caso particular yo te recomiendo comparar `if(numero == 5) {...}`